# Display excel data in a jsp page

Tags: java, html, excel, jsp

I have a web application in java/jsp. In our application there are multiple tabs and in one of the tab, I have to display the data from an excel sheet. I tried to convert the excel sheet into data.html file by using the save as webpage option. But when I try to include the html file in the tab, Im getting the below error message

```
This content cannot be displayed in a frame
```

I also tried to run the html file via the tomcat server in eclipse, but getting the above message. When i try to open it via a web browser, the data gets displayed properly.

I require help in getting the excel data displayed in a jsp page.  Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the URL of your web application, and what is the URL of that HTML file converted from Excel?

Comment: The url of the webapplication is "http://localhost:8080/pm/login.jsp. Im unable to run the html file using tomcat server. when I try to open the file in browser in eclipse, the URL that appears is file:///D:/PMProject/workspace/PM/WebContent/Data.html

Answer (score 0):

When the excel sheet is on your server side (Tomcat, Glassfish, Wildfly, or each other servlet container) you can use POI to deploy with some line codes something to read the excel file.

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream

Then you can create a little dynamic JSP ... to display the result in a HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout http://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/. Might help, if not please also check apache-poi.

Answer (score 0):

[Columns marked with read box willl be displayed i have attached image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XnUK.png)

> You can pass data from servlet to jsp using below code it works fine
>   Modules.java (Servlet page ) and Modules.jsp pages code is given below

```
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File("your_file_path"));
            System.out.println(file1);
            file.close();    
            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook111 = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet111 = workbook111.getSheetAt(0);


            Object[][] bookData_read = new String[sheet111.getLastRowNum()+1][3];

            int row_count11 = 0;

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator111 = sheet111.iterator();

            while (rowIterator111.hasNext()) 
            {
                Row row111 = rowIterator111.next();
                if (row_count11 == 0) {
                    row_count11++;
                continue;

                }

                if (row_count11 > sheet111.getLastRowNum())
                    break;



                Cell cell11 = row111.getCell(4);
                String cellvalue1 = "";

                if (cell11 != null && ! "".equals(cell11.getStringCellValue()) ||cell11 != null && ! "".equals(cell11.getNumericCellValue())) {

                    switch (cell11.getCellType()) {

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = cell11.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell11.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell11.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;

                    }}


                    String module1 = cellvalue1;
                    //System.out.println("module"+module1);
                    //System.out.println(cellvalue);
                    bookData_read[row_count11][0] = cellvalue1;


                    if(row111.getCell(5)!=null)
                    {
                          Cell cell2 = row111.getCell(5);
                          cellvalue1 = "";
                        if (cell2 != null && ! "".equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())) {



                    switch (cell2.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = cell2.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell2.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell2.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                    }  }}
                    String submodule = cellvalue1;
                    //System.out.println("submodule"+submodule);

                   // System.out.println(cellvalue);
                    bookData_read[row_count11][1] = cellvalue1;



                   if(row111.getCell(5)!=null && ! "".equals(row111.getCell(5).getStringCellValue()) )
                   {
    //               if(row.getCell(7)!=null && ! "".equals(row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue()))
    //              {
    //                    
                    Cell  cell3 = row111.getCell(8);
                    cellvalue1 = "";
                    if (cell3 != null && ! "".equals(cell3.getStringCellValue())) {
                    switch (cell3.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                            cellvalue1 = cell3.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell3.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                            cellvalue1 = "" + cell3.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;}}


                   String  temp = cellvalue1;
                   bookData_read[row_count11][2] = cellvalue1;

                   }
                    else{

                       continue;
                    }


                   row_count11++;



            }
            workbook111.close();

    request.setAttribute("modulesList", bookData_read);
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/All_Modules.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

> Modules.jsp page

```
<pre>  <%
    String[][] book_data = (String[][]) request.getAttribute("modulesList");
    System.out.println("book_data: " + book_data);
    %>
  <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="headings">

                            <th class="column-title"><center>Sr No. </center></th>
                            <th class="column-title"><center>Modules</center></th>
                            <th class="column-title"><center>Sub Modules </center></th>
                                  <th class="column-title"><center>Test Case ID</center></th>

                    <th class="column-title"><center>Select All&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="chkSelectAll btn btn-primary" /></center></th>
                         <th class="column-title"><center>Screen Shot&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></th>


                        </thead>
  <%
  int counter11 = 1;
  for (String[] device : book_data) {
      if (device[0] != null && device[2] != null) {
          System.out.println("device[0]: " + device[0]);
  %>
    <tr>
        <td><center><%=counter11 %></center></td>
        <td><center><%=device[0] %></center></td>
        <td><center><%=device[1] %></center></td>
        <td><center><%=device[2] %></center></td>

        <td><center><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat" name="selectedmodules" value=<%=device[2]%>></center></td>
        <td><center><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat" name="screenshots" value=<%=device[2]%>></center></td>

    </tr>

  <%
    counter11++;
      }
  }
  %>
                       </table>
    </pre>
```

Comment: just ignore <pre> </pre> tags delete that and add code in your jsp